# Parse JSON array inside array and bind with pdfmake

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, I'm trying to parse an array inside my array, I am not able to parse this array as using my code it comes up with an error Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0, I've searched all over the internet and there are many examples but non is working in my case, I don't understand what is wrong with my code, you assistance is much appreciated.

data

```
{ 
"employees":[ 
  { 
     "id":"f790cb86-4d41-401c-2a45-08d745b83164",
     "firstName_FL":"Employee Name",
     "employeeJobStatuses":[ 
        { 
           "id":"bd58a1a3-6dd7-4cd5-6c79-08d76cf25ba3",
           "status":"STATUS_ACTIVE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

employees.component.ts

```
   table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: [ '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*' ],
        alignment: 'center',
        body: [[
        {text: 'Name', style: 'header'}, 
        {text: 'Position', style: 'header'},
        {text: 'Department', style: 'header'},
        {text: 'Hiring Date', style: 'header'}, 
        {text: 'First Contracting Salary', style: 'header'},
        {text: 'Status', style: 'header'},
      ]]
            .concat(this.jsonObj.map((element, i) => 
            [
             element['firstName_FL'],
             element['position']['name_FL'],
             element['department']['name_FL'],
             element['hiringDate'].slice(0, 10),
             element['firstContractingSalary'],
             element.employeeJobStatuses.map((x, j) => ({ ...x,
              Status: x
            }))
            ]
            ))

      }
```

All is coming up with the result I need except this line JSON.parse(element['employeeJobStatuses']['status'])

Comment: element['employeeJobStatuses']['status']) this should be something like element['employeeJobStatuses'][i].status])

Comment: @EugeneSunic I've tried it but it came up with an error Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: your json in incorrect (input json), you are missing the array endings and commas

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question and corrected it

Comment: but still they persist...

Comment: @EugeneSunic I have corrected it now, please check again

Comment: please replace employees to employee

Comment: @kushalshah I put the json data wrong but now I have corrected it totally, the 5 elements that I'm trying to parse are working fine except the last one which is JSON.parse(element['employeeJobStatuses']['status'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your input to a valid JS object, afterwards do with it whatever needs to be done.

```js
// your input
const jsonString = JSON.stringify({
  "data": {
    "employee": [{
      "id": "f790cb86-4d41-401c-2a45-08d745b83164",
      "firstName_FL": "Employee Name",
      "employeeJobStatuses": [{
        "id": "bd58a1a3-6dd7-4cd5-6c79-08d76cf25ba3",
        "status": "STATUS_ACTIVE"
      }]
    }]
  }
})
// parse your input to js valid object
const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// do wathever you need to do
const newObj = jsonObj.data.employee.map((element, i) => ({
  ...element,
  employeeJobStatuses: element.employeeJobStatuses.map((x, j) => ({ ...x,
    status: x.status
  }))
}))

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but came up with same exact error

Comment: Could you somehow start from this example, because you cannot get the error out of it. I'm not even sure why do you need to parse twice ` JSON.parse(element['employeeJobStatuses']['status'])` if you already have a valid js object (data)

Comment: Okay since that I don't need to pass it twice, why is it coming up with this error though

Comment: I believe because of the first thing which we said
`element['employeeJobStatuses']['status']`, you need to do it like I did, map through your  element['employeeJobStatuses'] because it is an array you cannot just pull t status out of it

Comment: I have updated my code, all is working fine and getting the data except for employeeJobStatuses

Comment: It is working great now when I put it in an array element.employeeJobStatuses.map((x, j) => []

Thank you so much for your help, I would have never done it without you